# How to force a hook function in a properties getter?

Tags: swift

This question is re-edited from scratch. After a lot trials, I find that the main problem is designing a protocol which guarantees to execute a hook function before its certain property is accessed.

```
protocol Foo {
    var bar: Int { get }
    func hook()
}
```

And I want the following test to pass:

```
func testBarGetterShouldInvokeHooker() {
    class DummyFoo: Foo {
        var bar: Int = 0
        var invoked: Bool = false
        func hook() {
            invoked = true
        }
    }
    let foo = DummyFoo()
    _ = foo.bar
    XCTAssertTrue(foo.invoked)
}
```

Yes, I want that hook function to be hooked up automatically, that is -- not relying on the implementation struct/class to hook it explicitly.

I think this might be achieved by writing some nice extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by saying that your code has some errors, the main one is: where are you calling `hook()`?

There are some basic consideration to do. To get the `get` of `bar` called, `bar` has to be a computed property. To make it more generic, you should implement this variable in the protocol extension (by conforming, the behavior will be implemented by default).
How to provide the `Int` value? With a method, or an another variable

```
protocol Foo {
    func getBarValue() -> Int
    var invoked: Bool { get set }
}

extension Foo {

    var bar: Int {
        mutating get {
            hook()
            return getBarValue()
        }
    }

    mutating func hook() {
        print("Hook called")
        invoked = true
    }
}
```

The conform to the protocol

```
struct MyStruct: Foo {

    var invoked = false

    func getBarValue() -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}

var foo = MyStruct()
_ = foo.bar
```

Comment: I am aware of that there's no `hook()` call in my code, that's the question, I can't figure out how to write the proper extension that guarantees some dummy implementation like the one in the test method also has the auto-hooking feature. As for your answer, one may call `getBarValue` method directly thus by-pass invoking `hook`.

Comment: @NandiinBao you have to get that value from somewhere, and it has to be public.